# Swing - Images in Jpanel looks blurry on large screens

Tags: java, swing

There is a logo image displayed on Login screen inside JPanel. This image looks blurry on large monitor screens. Can anybody tell me how to fix the issue of blurred images, so that images looks sharp and clear on large monitor screens ?

1. Do I have to make high resolution images and scale down according to screen size ?

Below is the method to resize images in proportion.

```
public ImagePanel(String url, int w, int h) {
   try {    
       InputStream is = getFileFromResourceAsStream(url);
       image = ImageIO.read(is);
       imageurl = url;
       
       width=w;
       height=h;
       isscaled = true;
       outputImage = new BufferedImage(w,h, image.getType());
     
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Here how to calculate the new height and width to be passed as parameter according to screen size ?
Thank you.

Comment: *Do I have to make high resolution images and scale down according to screen size ?* - yes. Upscaled images will be pixelated.

Comment: *Here how to calculate the new height and width to be passed as parameter according to screen size?* I'm not sure that you have to downscale your hi-res image, then it would be upscaled again when displayed resulting blurry again ... or not?

Comment: Your code doesn't show this.  After you pack the JFrame but before you make the JFrame visible, you get the size of the image area, scale your image appropriately, add the image to the image area, and make the JFrame visible.